# Why missing parenthesis error in print Python2.7. When python 2.7 support no brackets?

Tags: python-2.7, scons, nvmain

I was running NVMain but got a python error. I'm using python 2.7.18, but ended up on missing parenthesis error and as I read everywhere python 2.7 supports no brackets but why the error is still existing. I am attaching a picture of error.[image]

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv? How did you install SCons?

Answer (score 1):

You're not using Python 2.7. You're using `scons`, which is choosing its own interpreter (I'm assuming it's a script, so you can just open it in a text editor, it likely has a shebang line at the top that refers to `python3`). As of `scons` version 4.0.0, it doesn't support Python below 3.5 at all, so your `SConscript` files need to be written in Python 3 compatible syntax.

Comment: ok...I just changed the python from 2.7 to 3.8 but still, the same problem persists. why?              umakant@umakant-Vostro-15-3568:~/$ python -V
Python 3.8.5
umakant@umakant-Vostro-15-3568:~/gem5-nvmain-hybrid-simulator-master/nvmain$ scons --build-type=fast
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
  File "/home/umakant/gem5-nvmain-hybrid-simulator-master/nvmain/build/SConscript", line 57

    print "Checking gem5 revision number...",

          ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Checking gem5 revision number...", end=" ")?

Comment: @Learning No, you got it backwards. No-parentheses `print` is a *Python 2* construct, and is invalid in Python 3. The problem is that scons is running your code using Python 3, not 2.

Comment: @Learning: As I said in the answer, rewrite your `scons`-related code (e.g. `SConscript`) to be Python 3 compatible, e.g. using `print` function (which requires parentheses), not `print` statement (Python 2-only weirdness). The `2to3` helper might do a lot of it for you, but all the possible things you might need to change are beyond the scope of StackOverflow; there were a handful of big, annoying things to deal with, and dozens of small, mostly automatable changes.